# Instagram API - Retrieve user info

Tags: php, instagram

I am trying to retrieve user info on my webpage using the api, but it does not return any info.

Index.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<Head>
<title>IG LP</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</Head>
<center>
<body>
<img src = "http://i.imgur.com/Q38jJG9.png">

<center>
<p>See your profile information on the next page</p>
<form role="form" method="post" action="getuser.php">
<div class="form-group">
<font color="white">Instagram name:</font>
<input type="Text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Your Instagram Name:">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
</div>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

getuser.php:

```html
 <?PHP
    
    $username = $_POST['username'];
 
 // Add your own access token bellow to make this script work
 $accesstoken = 'My Access token';
    $apiurl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q='.$username.'&access_token='.$accesstoken;
 
 //API call to grab profile pic, username, bio, website, full name, and id
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $apiurl);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
 $response = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 $json = json_decode($response, true);
 $pic = $json{'data'}[0]{'profile_picture'};
 $username = $json{'data'}[0]{'username'};
 $bio = $json{'data'}[0]{'bio'};
 $website = $json{'data'}[0]{'website'};
 $full_name = $json{'data'}[0]{'full_name'};
 $id = $json{'data'}[0]{'id'};
 
 
 // API call to grab Follows, Followed By, and amount of pics upload.  
 // Delete this if you don't need this info.
 $apiurl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$id.'/?access_token='.$accesstoken;
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $apiurl);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
 $response = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 $json = json_decode($response, true);
 $pics = $json{'data'}{'counts'}{'media'};
 $follows = $json{'data'}{'counts'}{'follows'};
 $followed_by = $json{'data'}{'counts'}{'followed_by'};

 
 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<Head>
<title>IG LP</title>
</Head>
<body>
<center>
<img src = "<?php echo $pic; ?>">
<p>Username: <?php echo $username; ?></p>
<p>Bio: <?php echo $bio; ?></p>
<p>Website: <?php echo $website; ?></p>
<p>Full Name: <?php echo $full_name; ?></p>
<p>ID: <?php echo $id; ?></p>
<p>Pics Uploaded: <?php echo $pics; ?></p>
<p>Following: <?php echo $follows; ?></p>
<p>Followed By: <?php echo $followed_by; ?></p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

What can I do to get the user info inserted in the textbox?

Comment: Have you turned on error-reporting?

Comment: No Thomas, how can i do it?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Thanks Thomas. As i am using localhost for test purposes before sending to the server, that option is already enabled in php.ini. The thing is:

You enter the username, click the button, and then it appears the username etc labels, but after it, the info i want doesn't appear.